# Access methods of existing Leaflet map on a website

Tags: javascript, console, leaflet, web-console

I'd like to [`flyTo()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-flyto) on an existing map on http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

When I type `map` into Firefox's (or Vivaldi's/Chromium's) web console, the `<div>` container is returned. How can I get the JS `map` variable to be able to call `map.flyTo(<LatLng>)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Unfortunately, the Leaflet Map initialization, on the demo page you link to, happens in a JavaScript IIFE, i.e. in a local self-contained scope:

https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers/blob/8833ac605c3e64da58700a79a75eca01463e7afe/preview/preview.js#L4

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl: false,
  }).setView([48, -3], 5);

  // more code...

})(); // End of IIFE
```

Therefore you will not be able to access that local `map` variable from an outer scope, i.e. from the `window` you have access to on your browser web console.

I am also not aware of a mean to retrieve the Map object from its DOM container by default in Leaflet.